# A linear algebra problem concerning generalized eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $V$ is a complex vector space of dimension $n$, $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is the vector space consisting of all linear transforms of $V$ and $A\in\mathrm{End}(V)$. Now we define a linear map induced by $A$ as follows
$$\varphi_A:\mathrm{End}(V)\longrightarrow\mathrm{End}(V), B\mapsto AB-BA.$$
For any eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ of $A$, we define the generalized eigenspaces to be
$$G(A,\lambda):=\{v\in V|\,(A-\lambda I_V)^mv=0,\text{for some}\ m\in\mathbb{Z}_+\},$$
where $I_V$ is the identity map of $V$. Prove that all of the generalized eigenspaces of $A$ are $B$-invariant if and only if $B$ belongs to the $0$-generalized eigenspace.

I know that the generalized eigenspace can be defined simply as $\{v\in V|\,(A-\lambda I_V)^nv=0\}=\ker(A-\lambda I_V)^n$ using one part of the proof of the Fitting lemma, and I am tring to use generalized eigenspace decomposition of $V$
$$V=\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^s\ker(A-\lambda_i I_V)^{n_i}$$
where $\lambda_i$ are all distinct and $\sum_{i=1}^sn_i=n$. Now I have proved by induction that
$$\varphi_A^n(B)=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}A^{n-i}BA^i$$
but I am stuck here, how can I solve this problem?And I wonder if there is some deeper theory here (Lie algebra)?